# Invoke-Command: continue if an exception occurs while sending a command to a Computer from a list

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-remoting

I'm attempting to perform a check for whether or not remoting is available on each computer of a list in parallel. I've started to do this via `Invoke-Command` and passing a list of IP addresses to the `-ComputerName` argument. The list looks something like this.

> 11.111.1.11
>
> 22.222.2.22
>
> 33.333.3.33

And so on. Here is the code so far, simplified for brevity.

```
try
{
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerList -ScriptBlock{ 
        //Do stuff 
    } -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -Credential $auth
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception
}

$result
```

This will work if the computer in the given list has remoting services available, but `Invoke-Command` will throw an exception if it's unable to send a remote command. To clarify, the computer is online and can be pinged, but is not able to receive commands over PSRemoting.

This in itself isn't an issue but when an exception occurs, `Invoke-Command` will not continue to do the rest of the computers in the list. The exception interrupts the process, but I'd like it to skip the failing computer (possibly mark it as a failure) without stopping.

I'd like to be able to do this in parallel because it would really help with the amount of computers I'm working with. It'd be a huge help if someone in the know could point me in the right direction with this. Thanks very much!

For those that might find it helpful, when forcing the exception message to be printed:

```
[XX.XXX.X.XX] Connecting to remote server XX.XXX.X.XX failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall
exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public
profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
```

Comment: tell `Invoke-Command` to _SilentlyContinue_ on all errors. then, after you get all the results back AND if you need to list the non-responders, compare the input list to the responder list to get the non-responders. here is a demo of the basic idea >>> Get CPU utilization on many computers quickly : PowerShell — https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8d7w0q/get_cpu_utilization_on_many_computers_quickly/ <<<

Comment: As it turns out, it seems ```Invoke-Command``` wasn't _really_ interrupted by the exception, and I was querying the returned object properties incorrectly. This was really helpful after I figured that out though, exactly what I was after, thank you very much!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to know that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]